# ProxyBeanMethods in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Can someone give a real case example of how using boolean element `proxyBeanMethods` is going to change how the application's bean interact with one another ? From my understand  setting `proxyBeanMethods` to `false` is similiar to using `@Lazy` annotation on  the dependencies of a bean in which those dependencies will only be created once the  methods that return them are called therefore improve the startup speed. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: `proxyBeanMethods` allows you to invoke one method marked as `Bean` from another one declared in the same configuration class.

Comment: @KenBekov ... and? how is that useful, though? I might miss you point here

Comment: Please see also this issue : [Make Spring web configuration classes use proxyBeanMethods=false by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23004)

Comment: And also, on Spring Security : [Switch to proxy-less configuration by leveraging @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6818)

Answer (score 37):

It isn't the same as `@Lazy` and this is also explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods--) of the property.

The default is `true` meaning each `@Bean` method will get proxied through  CgLib. Each call to the method will pass through the proxy and assuming singleton scoped beans, it will return the same instance each time the method is called.

When setting it to `false` no such proxy method will be created and each call to the method will create a new instance of the bean. It will act just as a factory method. This is basically the same as the so called [Bean Lite Mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html), or `@Bean` methods on non-`@Configuration` annotated classes.

Now the latter isn't the same as `@Lazy` which will only defer the construction to the moment it is needed.

Comment: I see but how setting proxyBeanMethods to false will improve the application start up time and memory usage ?

Comment: It might slightly improve startup time, as it doesn't need to create proxies for the configuration class. However use cautiosly as it changes the behavior of your methods (and might endup creating multiple instances of a bean instead of a single one! especiallly when combined with `@Lazy` as each call would create a new instance, effectivly leading to prototype scoped beans!).